# How to switch tomcat user on vFabric in STS

Tags: spring, tomcat

I log on my testing application as one of users in tomcat-users.xml for vFabric. Unfortunately I check the "save credential"(or "save password") option so I cannot change user on STS because the current credential seems stay on the server session and seems become constant and each time I log on the application it doesn't pop up the window for log on access and I automatically log on as the same user all the time. I have to run external web browsers to verify change to other roles.

So how can I cancel the "auto log-on" thing so I can user another user/role to work on STS/vFabric?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options.

1. Change the password for the user in the tomcat-users.xml file.
2. Go to the options/settings/whatever menu of the browser you are using and clear the saved credential for that host. Depending on the browser (e.g. some mobile browsers) you may only be able to clear all saved passwords. Then close the browser and re-open it to make sure ny session cookie is discarded.

Comment: Both ways work. I am so dumb not to think of the first way. Thank you Mark you rock !